# When i select "Record and run test on any open browser" and click Ok , IE is getting stuck and shows"Stopped working" Why so?

Tags: qtp

I re-registered the BHO manager,But its not Working.
Note: I'm using IE 9,
      QTP : 11.0 Trial version.

```
  In manage add-ons option: It shows Name:("Not verified" HP Developement ltd)
```

Is there any ways we can use other browsers but IE to test in qtp?

Comment: Which version of IE and which version of QTP?

Comment: Qtp : 11.0(trial period) and IE: 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 was not initially supported by QTP11 (QTP11 was released on August 2010 while IE9 was released half a year later on March 2011).

In order to gain support you must install patch [QTPWEB_00078](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM1166929).

Comment: Can we use any other browsers?Because i don't see any options related to it.

Comment: @Vignesh QTP11 with no additional patches supports IE 6-8 and Firefox 3.5

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with Browser Helper Object Manager, this can be resolved by unregistering and registering it again:

Type on the command line to re-register:

```
regsvr32 -u bhomanager.dll
regsvr32 bhomanager.dll
```

You can verify if the add on is installed correctly by opening IE, go to Tools, Select Manage Add-ons and Enable/Disable Add-ons.